# Get the string between two symbols in a string and push them to an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I will have a string like below

```
var str = "-#A 
This text belongs to A.
Dummy Text of A.
-#B
This text belongs to B.
Dummy Text of B.
-#C
This text belongs to C.
Dummy text of C.
-#Garbage
This string should be ignored"
```

I want an array like below ignoring text heading with "Garbage"

```
var arr = [["A","This text belongs to A.
Dummy Text of A."],["B","This text belongs to B.
Dummy Text of B."] etc...]
```

Please help me on this. How can I make it done...

Comment: I am assuming that your quote marks should be after "This string shold be ignored.." rather than after "Dummy text of C."

Comment: @Jeff Yes exactly.. I have edited. Thanks

Comment: is that just one line or "\n" new line are there???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str="...";
var ar=str.split('-#');
var res=new Array();
for (var s in ar) {
  if (s=='') continue;
  var b=ar[s].split('\n');
  var name=b.shift();
  if (name=='Garbage') continue;
  b=b.join('\n');
  res[res.length]=new Array(name,b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "a" is not declared above.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
str.match(/-#([A-Z]) ([a-zA-Z. ]+)/g).map(function (i) {
   return i.split(/-#([A-Z])/).splice(1)  
})
```

map won't work in IE 8 but there's a ton of shims. [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yYkfk/)

Comment: It is removing new lines in a string. Please use this fiddle. I made it easy to edit for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = str.split("-#");
var newStr=[];
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] != "" && str[i].substr(0,7) != 'Garbage') newStr.push(str[i]);
}
console.log(newStr);
```

A test jsFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WGu5U/).

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression exec can allow you to use a simpler pattern for the global match.

The match can include the '#Garbage' in an index that can be ignored when you build the array.

```
var str= "-#A This text belongs to A. Dummy Text of A.-#B This text belongs to B. Dummy Text of B.-#C This text belongs to C. Dummy text of C.-#Garbage This string should be ignored"



var M, arr= [], rx=/-#((Garbage)|(\w+)\s*)([^-]+)/g;
while((M= rx.exec(str))!= null){
    if(M[3]){
        arr.push(['"'+M[3]+'"', '"'+M[4]+'"']);
    }
}
// arr>>
// returned value: (Array)
[
    ["A", "This text belongs to A. Dummy Text of A."],
    ["B", "This text belongs to B. Dummy Text of B."],
    ["C", "This text belongs to C. Dummy text of C."]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are capture groups. When you have a regex that matches the appropriate section, you can use a capture group to grab that section and put it into an array. See the answer for [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex).

If you don't know how to use regex at all, you should look for a tutorial on it, and try some, so that you can get a more specific question and so that you can answer http://whathaveyoutried.com/.